# Failing to install scikit-learn in windows 8 - too complicated error

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip

I have installed Python 3.9 and the newest version of pip suggested by the terminal.
I also installed NumPy, SciPy, Seaborn, MatPlotLib (and JupyterLab, Voila although those are irrelevant).
When I go to the path where the scripts of Python are (using cmd.exe) and try the command
*pip install -U scikit-learn*
I get an extremelly long error.
I also tried:
*!pip install scikit-learn*
from a Jupyter notebook, but I get the same result.

```
Using cached scikit-learn-0.23.2.tar.gz (7.2 MB)
 Installing build dependencies: started
 Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
```

The error I get is the following:

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Στραβούλα\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w3wt_sg1\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation != '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (334 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX" and platform_python_implementation != "CPython"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-50.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Collecting Cython>=0.28.5
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Collecting numpy==1.17.3
    Using cached numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)
  Collecting scipy>=0.19.1
    Using cached scipy-1.5.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (31.4 MB)
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython, numpy, scipy
      Running setup.py install for numpy: started
      Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Στραβούλα\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1al5oc45\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Στραβούλα\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1al5oc45\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Στραβούλα\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1qm0ngw_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Στραβούλα\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w3wt_sg1\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Στραβούλα\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w3wt_sg1\overlay\Include\numpy'
           cwd: C:\Users\Στραβούλα\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1al5oc45\numpy\
      Complete output (308 lines):
      Running from numpy source directory.
  
      Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
      with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:
  
        - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                                 release)
        - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)
  
  
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      blis_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      customize GnuFCompiler
      Found executable C:\Perl64\site\bin\g77.exe
      gnu: no Fortran 90 compiler found
      gnu: no Fortran 90 compiler found
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifl
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      Could not locate executable f90
      Could not locate executable f77
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable DF
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efl
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Found executable C:\Strawberry\c\bin\gfortran.exe
      Using built-in specs.
      COLLECT_GCC=C:\Strawberry\c\bin\gfortran.exe
      COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
      Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
      Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-7.1.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh, Built by strawberryperl.com project' CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/opt/build/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v502/mingw64/opt/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/opt/build/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v502/mingw64/opt/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS=' -I/opt/build/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v502/mingw64/opt/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident -L/opt/build/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v502/mingw64/opt/lib -L/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib '
      Thread model: posix
      gcc version 7.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by strawberryperl.com project)
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_blas_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      accelerate_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      C:\Users\Στραβούλα\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1al5oc45\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
          Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
          Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
          A better performance should be easily gained by switching
          Blas library.
        self.calc_info()
      blas_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      C:\Users\Στραβούλα\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1al5oc45\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
          the BLAS environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
      blas_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      C:\Users\Στραβούλα\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1al5oc45\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
          the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
        self.calc_info()
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_lapack_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      customize GnuFCompiler
      gnu: no Fortran 90 compiler found
      gnu: no Fortran 90 compiler found
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Using built-in specs.
      COLLECT_GCC=C:\Strawberry\c\bin\gfortran.exe
      COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
      Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
      Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-7.1.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh, Built by strawberryperl.com project' CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/opt/build/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v502/mingw64/opt/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/opt/build/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v502/mingw64/opt/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS=' -I/opt/build/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v502/mingw64/opt/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident -L/opt/build/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v502/mingw64/opt/lib -L/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib '
      Thread model: posix
      gcc version 7.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by strawberryperl.com project)
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_clapack_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      customize GnuFCompiler
      gnu: no Fortran 90 compiler found
      gnu: no Fortran 90 compiler found
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Using built-in specs.
      COLLECT_GCC=C:\Strawberry\c\bin\gfortran.exe
      COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Strawberry/c/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/lto-wrapper.exe
      Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
      Configured with: ../../../src/gcc-7.1.0/configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/mingw64 --enable-shared --enable-static --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp --enable-libatomic --enable-lto --enable-graphite --enable-checking=release --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-bootstrap --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=core2 --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpfr=/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-mpc=/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-isl=/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static --with-pkgversion='x86_64-posix-seh, Built by strawberryperl.com project' CFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/opt/build/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v502/mingw64/opt/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -pipe -fno-ident -I/opt/build/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v502/mingw64/opt/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' CPPFLAGS=' -I/opt/build/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v502/mingw64/opt/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/include -I/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/include' LDFLAGS='-pipe -fno-ident -L/opt/build/x86_64-710-posix-seh-rt_v502/mingw64/opt/lib -L/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-zlib-static/lib -L/opt/build/prerequisites/x86_64-w64-mingw32-static/lib '
      Thread model: posix
      gcc version 7.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh, Built by strawberryperl.com project)
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      flame_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries flame not found in ['c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      lapack_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\στραβούλα\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      C:\Users\Στραβούλα\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1al5oc45\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
      lapack_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      C:\Users\Στραβούλα\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1al5oc45\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running install
      running build
      running config_cc
      unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
      running config_fc
      unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
      running build_src
      build_src
      building py_modules sources
      creating build
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils
      building library "npymath" sources
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Στραβούλα\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1al5oc45\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Στραβούλα\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1al5oc45\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Στραβούλα\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-1qm0ngw_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Στραβούλα\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w3wt_sg1\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Στραβούλα\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w3wt_sg1\overlay\Include\numpy' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\στραβούλα\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Στραβούλα\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w3wt_sg1\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation != '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Thanks in advance to anyone reading it.
I am more than gratefull to any person with any ideas about it.

Comment: Your system is not ready to compile numpy from sources (you don't want to do this on windows) and tries that, despite the fact that there are prebuild binaries available. According to the log this is due to `Using legacy 'setup.py install' for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.`. Try to analyze why this is happening: maybe it goes away after `pip install wheel`

Comment: Thank you @sascha  I just istalled wheel and retried installing scikit-learn afterwards but unfortunatelly I still get an error... :)

Comment: I also tried installing/upgrading *setuptools, numpy, scipy, wheel, Cython*, but I still get an almost identical error